# Evaluate $\int_a^b(x-a)^3(b-x)^4 dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate

$\int_a^b(x-a)^3(b-x)^4 dx $

with $0<a<b$.

I've tried the following substitutions :

$ y = b - x$

Giving,

$\int(b-a-y)^3(y)^4 dy $

Then,

$ z = y / (b-a)$

Giving,

$(b-a)^7\int(1-z)^3(z)^4 dz $

However, I'm not sure how the integration region changed in the process. I'm stuck here.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Thoughtful questions, even homework-related, are welcome. However, you should not expect others to do your homework for you, and it's inappropriate to post your homework verbatim. (That may not be what you're doing, but all people here can go by is appearances.) Instead, please try to ask questions about specific places where you're stuck, or about particular concepts you don't understand.

Comment: hint: $x-a = -(b-x)+b-a$

Comment: Hi, Andrew. Thanks.
It's not homework related, but I've edited my question to be more specific! sorry. :)

Comment: Thanks. :) You've got a good answer, but as a general matter, plugging the "old" limits (here, $x = a$ and $x = b$) into your substitution $z = (b - y)/(b - a)$ gives the "new" limits (here $z = 1$ and $z = 0$).

Answer (score 2):

If you use the substitution $z = \dfrac{b-x}{b-a}$ (which is the result of combining the two substitutions you used), then $dz = -\dfrac{1}{b-a}\,dx$. As for the bounds, as $x$ increases from $x = a$ to $x = b$, $z$ decreases from $z = 1$ to $z = 0$. So, you get this:

$\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}(x-a)^3(b-x)^4\,dx$ $= \displaystyle\int_{1}^{0}[(b-a)(1-z)]^3[(b-a)z]^4 \cdot -(b-a)\,dz$ $= (b-a)^8\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}(1-z^3)z^4\,dz$

The last integral is easy to evaluate if you use the expansion $(1-z)^3 = 1-3z+3z^2-z^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=a\sin^2y+b\cos^2y\implies dx=2a\sin y\cos y\ dy$

$x-a=(b-a)\cos^2y$ and $b-x=(b-a)\sin^2y$

If $x=a,(a-b)\cos^2y=0\implies y=\dfrac\pi2;$

Similarly, if $x=b, y=0$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: This is a **very** good hint, for sure ! Using it for $\int_a^b(x-a)^m(b-x)^n dx$ leads to a so beautiful answer ! Thank you.